# How plot graph with missing data lines?

Tags: gnuplot, lines

I have data recorded in time. But some data lines are missing and gnuplot replace them with long lines in these intervals.

How can i set gnuplot to draw nothing instead of draw lines in these intervals?

PS. I don't have free cells in these lines, I dont have these lines at all.

lines:

```
column 1  ... col 195 
13:30:20.8   0.78061899
13:30:21.8    5.969546498
13:32:19.8   17.21257881
13:32:20.8   6.922475345
```

[image: graph with long lines in interval]

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to draw a line between two points you must insert an empty line in the data file between the two point entries, so that effectively you have

```
13:30:20.8   0.78061899
13:30:21.8    5.969546498

13:32:19.8   17.21257881
13:32:20.8   6.922475345
```

This cannot be done with gnuplot directly, but you can use e.g. `awk` to do the processing on-the-fly:

```
set timefmt '%H:%M:%S'
set xdata time
filename = 'data.txt'
plot 'awk ''{split($1,d,":"); t_prev = t; t = (d[1] * 60 + d[2])*60 + d[3]; if (t_prev && (t - t_prev > 10)) print ""; print }'' '.filename with lines
```

Here, the gap threshold is 10 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your miss data identifier is "NaN", then you can use the following command

```
plot "data" using 1:($2) with linespoints
```

instead of

```
plot "data" using 1:2 with linespoints
```

The former one will ignore the missing data and treat it as blank line and therefore not draw a connecting line across the gap while the latter one will draw continuous, unbroken line.

Comment: No, this has nothing to do with 'NaN'. Some data points just have a large time gap between them.

Comment: This works for me. The advantage of this over the other answer (insert a blank line) is that technique this can be used when only some values are missing. There's nothing wrong with inserting a blank line, if you have no values, but there's nothing wrong with this answer either and it doesn't deserve the downvote.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the records: there are later questions about the same/similar issue.

[Avoid connection of points when there is empty data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39960349/7295599)

[How to remove line between "jumping" values, in gnuplot?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41088864/7295599)

[Removing vertical lines due to sudden jumps in gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46901179/7295599)

However, my solutions there require transparent color, which was not available in at the time of OP's question (gnuplot 4.6.5, Feb 2014). Nevertheless, there is a solution without external tools like `awk` or changing the data.

- First solution for gnuplot 4.6.: Instead of a transparent line you use a white line which, however, will cover the grid lines, although it will be hardly visible.
- Second solution for gnuplot 4.6 is using vectors. This really interrupts the line and will work for gnuplot 5.x as well.

**Data:**

```
 00:00:00    0.406406
 00:00:44    0.339779
 00:01:28    0.986602
 00:02:13    0.17746
 00:02:57    0.0580277
 00:03:42    0.586614
 00:04:26    0.84247
 00:05:11    0.597502
 00:05:55    0.0394846
 00:06:40    0.369416
 00:13:20    0.527109
 00:13:42    0.371411
 00:14:04    0.851465
 00:14:26    0.980312
 00:14:48    0.431391
 00:15:11    0.545491
 00:15:33    0.708445
 00:15:55    0.861669
 00:16:17    0.277122
 00:16:40    0.787273
```

**Script:**

```
### avoid showing a line across larger time gaps
reset

FILE = "SO26510245.dat"

myFmt = "%H:%M:%S"

tGap = 60    # 60 seconds
set format x "%H:%M"
set timefmt "%H:%M:%S"

set xdata time
set ytics 0.5
set key top center noautotitle
set grid x,y

set multiplot layout 3,1

    plot FILE u 1:2 w l lc rgb "red" ti "data as is"

    myColor(col) = (t0=t1, t1=timecolumn(1), t1-t0>tGap ? 0xffffff : 0x0000ff)
    plot t1=NaN FILE u 1:2:(myColor(1)) w l lc rgb var ti "white line"

    myGap(col) = (t1-t0>tGap ? NaN : y0)
    plot t1=y1=NaN FILE u (t0=t1,t1=timecolumn(1),t0):(y0=y1,y1=$2,myGap(0)):(t1-t0):(y1-y0) \
         w vec lc rgb "web-green" nohead ti "with vectors"

unset multiplot
### end of script
```

**Result:** (created with gnuplot 4.6.0, from March 2012)

[image]