# Drawing a graph with the y-axis aligning correctly

Tags: gnuplot

I have some data which I've put in a text file (fre.24.val). That data is formatted as:

time `tab` temperature `tab` temperature

The text file has 1440 rows, each row is a minute of a 24-hour period.

The first row corresponds to 24h minutes ago. The last line is 1m ago.

The first column is the time in HH:MM format, the second column is the temperature that corresponds to the time, the third column is the temperature corresponding to the same time 24 hours before.

`head fre.24.val -n1` produces:

18:52   -16.4   -17.3

`tail fre.24.val -n1` produces:

18:52   -17.0   -16.6

This indicates that the file is correctly formatted, and that is the order in which I want to draw the graph.

When I draw the graph using the plot dat a below, it works but the graph has the time as  midnight to midnight.

```
set title "" textcolor rgb "#995be0"
set xlabel "" textcolor rgb "#995be0"
set ylabel "" textcolor rgb "#995be0"
set grid
set term png transparent truecolor size 392, 200
set output "/var/www/html/img/freday.png"
set border lw 0

# Set the time format for the x-axis
set xdata time
set timefmt "%H:%M"
set format x "%l%p"

# Specify the line color and width
set style line 1 lc rgb "#995be0" lw 2
set style line 2 lc rgb "#cc995be0" lw 2

# Specify the x-axis tick interval to 10 minutes
set xtics "00:00", 14400
set xtics textcolor rgb "#995be0"

# Specify the number of items on the y-axis
set ytics 1 textcolor rgb "#995be0"

# Remove the key (legend)
unset key

plot "fre.24.val" using 1:2 smooth csplines with lines ls 1, \
"" using 1:3 smooth csplines with lines ls 2
```

[image]

I've tried using the following plot:

```
set title "" textcolor rgb "#995be0"
set xlabel "" textcolor rgb "#995be0"
set ylabel "" textcolor rgb "#995be0"
set grid
set term png transparent truecolor size 392, 200
set output "/var/www/html/img/freday.png"
set border lw 0

# Set the time format for the x-axis
set xdata time
set timefmt "%H:%M"
set format x "%l%p"

# Specify the line color and width
set style line 1 lc rgb "#995be0" lw 2
set style line 2 lc rgb "#cc995be0" lw 2

# Specify the x-axis tick interval to 10 minutes
set xtics "00:00", 14400
set xtics textcolor rgb "#995be0"

# Specify the number of items on the y-axis
set ytics 1 textcolor rgb "#995be0"

# Remove the key (legend)
unset key

# Set the x-axis range from -24 hours to current time
start_time = time(0) - 24*60*60
end_time = time(0)
set xrange [start_time:end_time]

plot "fre.24.val" using 1:2 smooth csplines with lines ls 1, \
'' using 1:3 smooth csplines with lines ls 2
```

But that results in the error:

```
plot "fre.24.val" using 1:2 smooth csplines with lines ls 1, '' using 1:3 smooth csplines with lines ls 2
                                                                                                                           
^
"fre.24.plot" line 34: all points y value undefined!
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

=============UPDATE=============

Ok, so I've gone ahead and changed the python script and it's now saving the data as "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"

and the new plot data is :

```
reset session
SecPerDay = 24*3600
tnow      = time(0)
tStart    = tnow - SecPerDay
tEnd      = tnow

set datafile separator ","
set title "" textcolor rgb "#995be0"
set xlabel "" textcolor rgb "#995be0"
set ylabel "" textcolor rgb "#995be0"
set grid
set term png transparent truecolor size 392, 200
set output "/var/www/html/img/freday.png"
set border lw 0

# Set the time format for the x-axis
set xrange[tStart:tEnd]
set xdata time
set timefmt "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
set format x "%l%p"

# Specify the line color and width
set style line 1 lc rgb "#995be0" lw 2
set style line 2 lc rgb "#cc995be0" lw 2

# Specify the x-axis tick interval to 10 minutes
set xtics "00:00", 14400
set xtics textcolor rgb "#995be0"

# Specify the number of items on the y-axis
set ytics 1 textcolor rgb "#995be0"

# Remove the key (legend)
unset key

# Set the x-axis range from -24 hours to current time
start_time = time(0) - 24*60*60
end_time = time(0)
set xrange [start_time:end_time]

today     = strptime("%Y%m%d",strftime("%Y%m%d",tnow))
esterday = today - SecPerDay
myTime(n) = (t0=t1, t1=timecolumn(1,"%H:%M"), $0==0 ? ( dt=0, t00 = t1>0 ? yesterday : today) : 0, \
             t1<t0 ? dt=dt+SecPerDay : 0, t00+t1+dt)

plot t1=NaN "/home/jim/gnuplot/fre.24.val" using 1:2 smooth unique with lines ls 1, \
t1=NaN '' using 1:3 smooth csplines with lines ls 2
```

A nd now I'm not entirely certain waht the timne range on the thing is, but it's certainly not ending in "now" which is around 19:00 when the graph was drawn

[image]

The data in it is a little screwy because the machine wasn't storing the temperatures for a while. Also, I had to change the csplines to unique otherwise it'd draw a massive curve because of the missing data.

Comment: What is your original data format? I would have assumed e.g. just time vs. temparature in two columns in a daily file. Unfortunately the date is missing or is it in the filename? Why don't you simply plot the last 24 h hours and the last 48 h hours on top of each other?

Comment: right now - 3 columns, example data: `2023-05-21 12:47,-17.2,-18.1`

Comment: ok, is there a specific reason why you put the temperature 24-48 h ago into the third column? I would assume you have a logger and it simply writes the timestamp and the temperature in the second column. So, why not simply taking the data of the last two days but plotting it wrapped into 24 hours?

Comment: btw, `smooth unique` will do nothing in your case, because your timestamps are unique already. There will be no "smoothing" or averaging. If you want to remove lines when you have missing data see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72535613/7295599

Comment: I had it as csplines instead of unique, and because the missing data was just before 4PM, it forced a massive spline that dipped down to about -45, which made the graph look bad.

Comment: is the actual problem now solved?

Answer (score 1):

You are in the unfortunate situation that your timestamps have no date but only a daytime, hence, the data will be wrapped at midnight. This makes plotting a bit more difficult because you have to unwrap your data.

A straightforward solution would be to add the actual date to the time.
Your data is from the last 24 hours, hence, it starts either at `00:00` (today) or at a time `>00:00` (yesterday) you have to add either yesterday's or today's date to your daytime.

Daytime is strictly increasing, but whenever the current timestamp `t1` (i.e. daytime in format `"%H:%M"`) is smaller than the previous one `t0` (i.e. crossing midnight) add one day to `dt`.

The x format in the example below is currently `"%H:%M\n%d.%m.%Y"` just to illustrate that the "absolute" date has been added.
You can simply change it to `"%H:%M"` or `"%l%p"` or whatever you like.

Actually, it might be easier to add the date into the original files and simply plot the last 24 / 48 hours.

By the way, just to mention: if your first line is `18:52 -16.4 -17.3` and the last line is `18:52 -17.0 -16.6` and you have a line for every minute then you should have 1441 (not 1440) data lines.

**Script:**

```
### unwrap time data
reset session

SecPerDay = 24*3600
tnow      = time(0)
tStart    = tnow - SecPerDay
tEnd      = tnow

# create some random test data
set table $Data
    set samples 1440
    y0 = y1 = 20
    plot '+' u (strftime("%H:%M",tStart + $0*60)):(y0=y0+rand(0)-0.5):(y1=y1+rand(0)-0.5) w table
unset table

set xrange[tStart:tEnd]
set format x "%H:%M\n%d.%m.%Y" timedate

today     = strptime("%Y%m%d",strftime("%Y%m%d",tnow))
yesterday = today - SecPerDay
myTime(n) = (t0=t1, t1=timecolumn(1,"%H:%M"), $0==0 ? ( dt=0, t00 = t1>0 ? yesterday : today) : 0, \
             t1<t0 ? dt=dt+SecPerDay : 0, t00+t1+dt)

plot t1=NaN $Data u (myTime(0)):2 w l lc "red" ti "last 24 hours", \
     t1=NaN    '' u (myTime(0)):3 w l lc "grey" ti "day before"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:**

If you can be sure that your data is regular with strict steps of 1 minute you can do it easier. Simply store the first time in `t0` (i.e. when line index `$0==0` and add `$0*60` for every line.

**Script:** (similar result as above)

```
### unwrap time data
reset session

SecPerDay = 24*3600
tnow      = time(0)
tStart    = tnow - SecPerDay
tEnd      = tnow

# create some random test data
set table $Data
    set samples 1440
    y0 = y1 = 20
    plot '+' u (strftime("%H:%M",tStart + $0*60)):(y0=y0+rand(0)-0.5):(y1=y1+rand(0)-0.5) w table
unset table

set xrange[:] noextend
set format x "%H:%M" timedate

plot $Data u ($0==0 ? t0=timecolumn(1,"%H:%M") : 0, t0+$0*60):2 w l lc "red" ti "last 24 hours", \
        '' u ($0==0 ? t0=timecolumn(1,"%H:%M") : 0, t0+$0*60):3 w l lc "grey" ti "day before"
### end of script
```

**Addition 2:**

Another suggestion. If you have a temperature logger, the most reasonable would be if the logger just writes the measured values together with a timestamp to a 2-column file. As I understand, you want to plot the last 24 hours and the last 48-24 hours on top of each other as function of daytime.

The first what comes to my mind is:

- limit the time axis range to the absolute time of the last 24 hours, i.e. `set xrange [now-24h : now]`
- for the first plot command plot the data as-is.
- for the second plot command filter the data: if it is in the range (48 to 24 hours before now) add 1 day (to shift it to today) else make the value `NaN` which will not be plotted.

There would be other solutions, e.g. using the modulo operator `%` wrapping all data into 24 hours.

**Script:**

```
### wrap last 48 hours into 24 hours
reset session

myTimeFmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M"
SecPerDay = 24*3600
tEnd      = time(0)    # now

# create some random test data
set print $Data
    N  = 3         #  N days back
    y0 = 20
    do for [i=0:N*SecPerDay:600] {
        print sprintf("%s, %g", strftime(myTimeFmt,tEnd-N*SecPerDay + i), y0=y0+rand(0)-0.5)
    } 
set print

set datafile separator comma
set xrange[tEnd-SecPerDay:tEnd] noextend
set format x "%H:%M" timedate

timeShift(col) = (t=timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt), t>=tEnd-2*SecPerDay && t<tEnd-SecPerDay ? t+SecPerDay : NaN) 

plot $Data u (timecolumn(1,myTimeFmt)):2 w l lc "red" ti "last 24 hours", \
        '' u (timeShift(1)):2 w l lc "grey" ti "last 48-24 hours"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I could always add the date as well. I'll mess around with this later and then try it out. I was hoping that gnuplot would just take the data line for line. Also as for the 1440 vs 1441 lines, when I `wc-l` the file it comes out at 1440, I know that if the same time is 1st line and last line it SHOULD be 1441, but I'm not going to dig into that too much, as reading 1441 lines of that file one at a time would break me! :-D

Comment: @Jim ok, if you can be sure that each line really corresponds to a minute and no times are missing you could do it simpler. Store the first time and add a minute for each line. I will add an example asap.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the xtics every 10 minutes you should consider

`set xtics "00:00", 10*60 ## now it is 10 minutes (4 hours seem to be better for a whole day range)`

Later when you specify the temporal range you use `time(0)` that gives you the current time epoch (seconds since Jan 1st 1970). Specifically, this gives you the date at the moment of execution plus hour of the day. In your data you only have time of the day and you do not specify the date.

Comment: yeah, having the time on the x-axis specified 240 times on a graph that's only a few hundred pixels wide would be painful, Right now i'm going for 1 every 4 hours. However, recording time in eopch might help.